# Leave only two decimal places after the dot

Tags: c#, ping, decimal-point

```
public void LoadAveragePingTime()
{
    try
    {
        PingReply pingReply = pingClass.Send("logon.chronic-domination.com");
        double AveragePing = (pingReply.RoundtripTime / 1.75);

        label4.Text = (AveragePing.ToString() + "ms");                
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        label4.Text = "Server is currently offline.";
    }
}
```

Currently my label4.Text get's something like: "187.371698712637".

I need it to show something like: "187.37"

Only two posts after the DOT. Can someone help me out?

Comment: FYI - I think you meant it should display 187.3*7*, not .34

Answer (score 204, accepted):

`string.Format` is your friend.

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
```

Comment: And again I'm astonished at the speed of this site. Thanks for the help, works great!

Comment: @Steve, yep looks that way!  At least you got more rep :P

Comment: Yeah, that's why you have 11k.

Comment: this changes the type of the decimal and you need to convert back to decimal again if you want to have a decimal. I think that Math.Round(x, 2) is the better answer if you want to maintain decimal without converting back and forth. Rounding the 3rd digit into 2nd digit also makes sense if it is greater than 5.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on what you need. In this case, he needed a string, so that's what I showed. Also, to be clear, `String.Format` handles the rounding the same way `Math.Round` does.

Answer (score 80):

If you want to take just two numbers after comma you can use the Math Class that give you the round function for example :

```
float value = 92.197354542F;
value = (float)System.Math.Round(value,2);         // value = 92.2;
```

Hope this Help 
Cheers

Comment: I have float value. so how can I do the same thing. I tried above method but it gives syntax error cannot convert type float to double

Answer (score 39):

```
// just two decimal places
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4);         // "123.40"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.0);         // "123.00"
```

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

*edit*

No idea why they used "String" instead of "string", but the rest is correct.

Comment: String is the same as string in C#.  I'm not sure why the language has both, but it does.

Comment: Which to use is a good question. What will happen if string is later mapped to a faster String2 class? Will that class have the same Format method?

Comment: I think that it's preferred style to use String for static function calls

Comment: @Yuriy - We'll cross that bridge when we have to deal with a faster String2 class (that I certainly hope has a better name)

Comment: How could you have something better than String2, SuperString? and its faster brother SuperAwesomeString?

Comment: .Net has System.String, or String for short.  C# has string, a native type that maps to System.String.  You can use one in the place of the other, but when programming C#, there's no reason to use the non-C# name, not even in statics.  Of course, due to common FormatWith extension methods, the question of whether to capitalize string for static calls becomes less relevant.

Answer (score 12):

```
yourValue.ToString("0.00") will work.
```

Answer (score 9):

```
double amount = 31.245678;
amount = Math.Floor(amount * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)

Answer (score 7):

**You can use this**

> *"String.Format("{0:F2}", String Value);"*

Gives you only the two digits after Dot, exactly two digits.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
double result = Math.Round(24.576938593,2);
MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

Output: 24.57

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution:

```
double totalCost = 123.45678;
totalCost = Convert.ToDouble(String.Format("{0:0.00}", totalCost));

//output: 123.45
```

Answer (score 3):

`double doublVal = 123.45678;`

There are two ways.

1. for display in string:

   ```
   String.Format("{0:0.00}", doublVal );
   ```
2. for geting again Double

   ```
   doublVal = Convert.ToDouble(String.Format("{0:0.00}", doublVal ));
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you may also use the composite operator F then indicating how many decimal spots you wish to appear after the decimal.

```cs
string.Format("{0:F2}", 123.456789);     //123.46
string.Format("{0:F3}", 123.456789);     //123.457
string.Format("{0:F4}", 123.456789);     //123.4568
```

It will round up so be aware of that.

I sourced the general documentation. There are a ton of other formatting operators there as well that you may check out.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Using the property of `String`

```
double value = 123.456789;
String.Format("{0:0.00}", value);
```

Note: This can be used to display only.

Using `System.Math`

```
double value = 123.456789;
System.Math.Round(value, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
public static string PreciseDecimalValue(double Value, int DigitsAfterDecimal)
        {
            string PreciseDecimalFormat = "{0:0.0}";

            for (int count = 2; count <= DigitsAfterDecimal; count++)
            {
                PreciseDecimalFormat = PreciseDecimalFormat.Insert(PreciseDecimalFormat.LastIndexOf('}'), "0");
            }
            return String.Format(PreciseDecimalFormat, Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string interpolation `decimalVar:0.00`

Comment: Perhaps there is more you could add to your question, maybe you can explain why this solves the problem, some background on interpolation?

Comment: instead using String.Format string interpolation allows easier and more intuitive string formatting.