# Trimming a float

Tags: c#, winforms, floating-point, digit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Leave only two decimal places after the dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291483/leave-only-two-decimal-places-after-the-dot)
>   [Formatting a float to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356351/formatting-a-float-to-2-decimal-places)

If I have a float that consists of something like 153.2154879, is there any way to convert it to string but only show 4 decimal places? I know I can format it using `"000.000"`, but the front number doesnt always have to be 3 digits. So is there a way to show all the front numbers (153), but only the first 4 characters after the point in a string?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1291483/962091

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually use a format string like `"#0.0000"`.

Comment: So the `#` just means show all the characters? Never knew about this thanks!

Comment: -1. Converting a float to string and then back to float just to **round it** makes no sense.

Comment: Why are you going around downvoting everyone Aliostad? I clearly stated I wanted to show 4 decimal places, I never said I wanted to round it and convert it back to float!

Comment: @Aliostad where are we converting the number back to float?

Comment: Sorry guys my bad. Can you edit your answer so I can make my downvote upvote?

Answer (score 8):

Something like this should do:

```
your_number.ToString("0.####");
```

This will show a max of 4 decimal places.

Comment: `your_number.ToString("0.####")` would be more efficient, as well as offering culture-sensitive overloads.

Comment: -1. Converting a float to string and then back to float just to **round it** makes no sense.

Comment: @Aliostad rounding and truncating are 2 different things. Formatting a number 2 a max of 4 decimal places is not rounding. I updated my answer to include a more "efficient approach" as suggested by phoog.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the C# function Math.Round function.

`float a= 153.213456;`
`Math.Round(a,3);`
this would round up the number to 153.213
then get convert it to string.

Comment: The string formatting code is going to round the number again; there's no reason to call Math.Round first.

Comment: @phoog Do you mean you convert the float to string and then convert back to float and not use the Round which is designed for the float??

Comment: @Aliostad of course not!  The question is about *displaying* a float with a given number of decimal points, which means *converting it to a string* with that number of decimal points.  I mean that *it is inefficient to use `Round` for the purpose of formatting a number for display.*  If the requirement is to have a rounded `float` in IEEE single binary format, for storage or calculation, then of course you should use `Round`.

Comment: @phoog I think Aliostad confuses truncating with rounding. See his comment to my answer.