# How to display values only upto 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table column "Amount" of type money. When I am retrieving its value through a store procedure, it returns the value upto 4 decimal places(because of type money). I  want the value upto two decimal places and I want it to handle in the code. How will I do it by rounding off the value to 2 decimal place. Thanks

Comment: Can have a look at the answer in the below link.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37997363/4619541

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I tried it and got the correct result.

Below is the code that I used:

```
funding.amount= Math.Round(decimal.Parse(dr["Amount"].ToString()), 2).ToString();
```

//since the amount was of string type, therefore I used the above code. we can also use the below code:

```
decimal.Round(yourValue, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s0xa85y.aspx

Answer (score 24):

Read [Custom Numeric Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) for detailed instructions on formatting numbers.

```
value.ToString("0.00");
```

In C# 6 or later, you can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) for a somewhat cleaner syntax.

```
$"{value:0.00}";
```

Comment: +1. This one is better if you always want 2 decimal places even if value has only 1 say. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Format in presentation layer:

```
string.Format("{0:#.##}", value);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string.Format("{0:0.00}", your_value);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. Also the comment by @Md. Shafiqur Rahman links to the same solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Standard Numeric Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)
Example:

```
decimal dValue = 1.268;
string sValue = dValue.ToString("N"); // 1.27
```

Answer (score 1):

In Leave Event write this code

```
 Double x;
        Double.TryParse(txtLocl.Text, out x);
        txtLocl.Text = x.ToString("0.00");
```

After leaving it allowed only two decimal places

Answer (score 0):

test this code:

```
value.ToString("F2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Text='<%#Bind("Value","{0:F2}") %>'
```