# Include trailing zeroes after rounding off a decimal/double value

Tags: c#, math

I am using Math.Round() Method to round off a double value. But I want to keep the trailing zeroes.
For Example:

```
double x = 0.4701589;
Math.Round(x*100,2);
```

This returns 4.7 however the desired output is 4.70

Comment: Is `value` `double` or `decimal`? `double` doesn't retain any precision information.

Comment: You are getting `4.7` it's just equivalent to`4.70000000`. It's not about rounding but display.

Comment: Its a double. not decimal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display values only upto 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288134/how-to-display-values-only-upto-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Then the answer is no. The `double` type is incapable of storing a distinction between `4.7` and `4.70`.

Comment: In math, there's no difference between 4.7 and 4.70. This is a display issue.

Comment: Then, is there a way, we can convert this double to decimal with 2 decimal points?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, for numeric types there is no difference between 4.7 or 4.70 or 4.7000000000000. Are you wanting to display this value to 2 decimal places as a string?

Comment: i want to pass this as decimal in api response with 2 decimal places

Comment: Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(value*100), 2) will give correct results?

Comment: @murli: if you pass it in an api response, there is no difference between 4.7 and 4.70. On the receiving end both will be deserialized to the same value.

Comment: What do you expect 4.605 to be rounded to?

Comment: Have you considered using `decimal` rather than `double`? https://dotnetfiddle.net/ReWIuo

Comment: we are expecting it to be 4.61

Comment: @murli `Math.Round` won't do that without specifying a midpoint rounding parameter. By default it will be 4.6 / 4.60 (bankers' rounding). A common mistake with `Math.Round`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with the rounding but with the formatting of your result. You can specify it needs to be printed with 2 decimals:

```
        double x = 0.04701589;
        double y = Math.Round(x*100, 2);

        Console.WriteLine($"default formatting: {y}");
        Console.WriteLine($"specify 2 digits: {y:f2}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .ToString("0.00") whenever you want to display it

```
Console.WriteLine(finalValue.ToString("0.00"));
```

Comment: This prints `4.7`, not `4.70`. Also after your update.

Comment: This does change the internal representation of the `decimal`. It's a valid answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity What makes it valid? `Console.WriteLine(x);` produces `4.7`

Comment: @AmirJabari Have you even tried it? I guess not, because what you say **does not produce `4.70`**.

Comment: It doesn't work at https://dotnetfiddle.net/TfqJBb .

Comment: Yes, I now admit my mistake. '0' not '#'. I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int numDigitsAfterPoint = 5;
double num = 1.25d;
string result = num.ToString("F" + numDigitsAfterPoint);
```

Keep in mind that, ToString uses the MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero instead of the MidpointRounding.ToEven (also called Banker's Rounding). As an example:

```
var x1 = 1.25.ToString("F1");
var x2 = 1.35.ToString("F1");
var x3 = Math.Round(1.25, 1).ToString();
var x4 = Math.Round(1.35, 1).ToString();
```

These will produce different result (because Math.Round normally uses MidpointRounding.ToEven)