# How to display two digits after decimal every time using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, format, decimal

I have a process, in which client want me to always display amount with two decimals either have value with decimal or not

example: if **17** then i want to display "17.00" and if 17.2 then i want to display "17.20"
or  if 17.2033 then i want to display "17.20" i have tried `String.Format("{0:.##}", rec.Rate)`

it does not works, please help me how can i do it.. thanks in advance

Comment: What about `String.Format("{0:0.00}", rec.Rate)`?

Comment: Please check out this similar answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291483/leave-only-two-decimal-places-after-the-dot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
double num=17.2;
string str=num.toString("0.00");
```

or this one.

```
double num=17.2;
string str=num.toString("N2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
double d=23.45;//any value here
String s=d.ToString("N2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this similar answer:

[Leave only two decimal places after the dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291483/leave-only-two-decimal-places-after-the-dot)

Check out what each of these return :

`String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"`

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4);         // "123.40"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.0);         // "123.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `String.Format("{0:.##}", rec.Rate)`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> `0` - Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is
>   present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.
>
> `#`-Replaces
>   the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is present;
>   otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.