# How do I get the first 2 decimals to appear instead of a long decimal?

Tags: java

This is a short and hopefully simple question, but I am trying to display an integer (if the product equals an integer), but I am wondering how to display the first 2 decimal places instead of the whole long one? For example: **48.23** instead of **48.2398484848438434323324**

Thank you.

Comment: This has been asked before...

Comment: check this link, repeated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910752/how-to-display-two-digits-after-decimal-every-time-using-c

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("%.2f",48.2398484848438434323324);
```