# float precision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my float to only display first 2 number behind the dot. I don't know how to search on google because my English is not that good but here is what I want in C#

```
float exampleFloat = 1.32232313F
Console.WriteLine(exampleFloat)
```

normally this would write in console `1.32232313F` right?
I want this number to be `1.32`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leave only two decimal places after the dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291483/leave-only-two-decimal-places-after-the-dot)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Like this:

> Round a float value to 2 decimal places in C#

```
float f = 10.123456F;
float fc = (float)Math.Round(f, 2);
```

> Output : 10.12

Comment: What's wrong with `Math.Round(f, 2)`?

Comment: I have editted it thanks for the tip!

Comment: I am writing this on Unity and it says The name 'Math' does not exist in the current context

Comment: the previous one worked tho xD

Comment: Since a `float` cannot accurately store a number like this, rounding to two is at best hoping for whatever is going to display it agrees with the truncation/rounding.  It's better to (instead, or additionally) consider where the two digits are needed, such as when displaying as text, and then using formatting rules then to limit it.

Comment: If your issue is with the display of data, then change how the data is displayed.  Don't modify the data unless the data actually needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a joke... I am new here and I wanna help and be helped so.

here is the answer.

for writing to console with just the formatting

```
    float exampleFloat = 1.32232313F;
    Console.WriteLine(exampleFloat.ToString("0.00"));
```

if you wanna just round them in the variable as is.

```
    Math.Round(exampleFloat,2);
```

to save the variable that way so if you wanna perform further operations.